# Type alias from property that might be null with strictNullChecks

Tags: angular, typescript, strictnullchecks, graphql-codegen

I am using `graphql-codegen/typescript-apollo-angular` to generate typescript code can be useed in our Angular application.
We decided to enable `strictNullChecks` the only issue is that we use the following pattern to specify the types of inner nodes that are returned by the API:

```
type ListSomethingEdge = ListSomethingQuery["something"]["edges"][0];
```

In my case `something` is generated as a `Maybe<Array<...>>` which is correct.
When I enable `strictNullChecks` the above code does not work anymore as something might be undefined / null as well.

```
Property 'edges' does not exist on type '({ __typename?: "SomethingConnection" | undefined; } & Pick<SomethingConnection, "totalCount"> & { edges?: Maybe<{ __typename?: "SomethingEdge" | undefined; } & { ...; }>[] | null | undefined; pageInfo: { ...; } & Pick<...>; }) | null | undefined'.ts(2339)
```

I was unable to find documentation on how to remove `null` / `undefined` types from a type alias like this. Maybe there is a different way to do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To remove `null` / `undefined` from the type you can use [NonNullable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullablet) utility.

> `NonNullable<T>` constructs a type by excluding `null` and `undefined` from `T`

```
type ListSomethingEdge = NonNullable<ListSomethingQuery["something"]>["edges"][0];
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/C4TwDgpgBAMglgZ2AZQPYFsLABZwHYDmAigK4QBOIUAvFAN5QIZa6EBc9UEAJgRAhzwl0AIwoBtALpQAvlAA+UIQBtlCqCTzcIAM3w9ZAKEOhIsRCmY58BAKK9otAHKo8TkqoCGI5RAA88EhomNaEpBQg4gBETCGsBFGSAHzRPHwIieIADJIA3EA)

---

`NonNullable` utility is built with [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types)

```
type NonNullable<T> = T extends null | undefined ? never : T
```

** You don't need to define it manually, typescript provides it and it is available globally.